# Reading log files in python

Tags: python

I have a log file (it is named data.log) containing data that I would like to read and manipulate.

The file is structured as follows:

'''

```
#Comment line 1
#Comment line 2 
1.00000000,3.02502604,343260.68655952,384.26845401,-7.70828175,-0.45288215
2.00000000,3.01495320,342124.21684440,767.95286901,-7.71506536,-0.45123853
3.00000000,3.00489957,340989.57100678,1151.05303883,-7.72185550,-0.44959182
```

'''

I would like to obtain the numbers from the last two columns and convert this into separate arrays or lists, I tried doing this by creating an empty list, but I do not know how to make this from a log file with a certain name. Could someone help me with this as I am a beginner programmer?

The expected output I would like to obtain is:

list1 = [-7.70828175, -7.71506536, -7.71506536]
list2 = [-0.45288215, -0.45123853, -0.44959182]

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Please, add the expected output sample to better understand.

Comment: Please, check [why is "Can someone help me?" not an actual question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/284236/why-is-can-someone-help-me-not-an-actual-question)

Comment: @Masud Morshed I have added the expected output to my question

Sorry if my question was unclear initially, I have added my expected output to the question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this way. but you have to confirm that each row list length must equal to 6.

```
list1 = []
list2 = []
with open('example.log') as f:
    for i in f.readlines():
        if (len(i.split(',')) == 6):
            list1.append(i.split(',')[4])
            list2.append(i.split(',')[5])

print(list1)
print(list2)
```

Comment: Welcome, If it works then mark it as solved or accept.