# Reading data from log file in Python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Im trying to read data from a log file I have in Python. Suppose the file is called data.log.
The content of the file looks as follows:

```
# Performance log
# time, ff, T vector, dist, windnorth, windeast
0.00000000,0.00000000,0.00000000,0.00000000,0.00000000,0.00000000
1.00000000,3.02502604,343260.68655952,384.26845401,-7.70828175,-0.45288215
2.00000000,3.01495320,342124.21684440,767.95286901,-7.71506536,-0.45123853
3.00000000,3.00489957,340989.57100678,1151.05303883,-7.72185550,-0.44959182
```

I would like to obtain the last two columns and put them into two separate lists, such that I get an output like:

list1 = [-7.70828175, -7.71506536, -7.71506536]

list2 = [-0.45288215, -0.45123853, -0.44959182]

I have tried reading the data with the following code as shown below, but instead of separate columns and rows I just get one whole column with three rows in return.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

file = open('data.log', 'r')

df = pd.read_csv('data.log', sep='\\s+')

df = list(df)

print (df[0])
```

Could someone indicate what I have to adjust in my code to obtain the required output as indicated above?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What's the problem with the answer you accepted in [your other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66797111/reading-log-files-in-python)?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Reading log files in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66797111/reading-log-files-in-python)

Comment: It works but I am trying to do it in a different way using pandas as a solution

Comment: `df = pd.read_csv('data.log', skiprows=3, header=None)` Use skiprows since you dont want that row with all 0s

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import pandas as pd 
df = pd.read_csv('sample.txt', skiprows=3, header=None, 
                 names=['time', 'ff', 'T vector', 'dist', 'windnorth', 'windeast'])
spam = list(df['windeast'])
print(spam)
# store a specific column in a list
df['wind_diff'] = df.windnorth - df['windeast'] # two different ways to access columsn
print(df)
print(df['wind_diff'])
```

output

```
[-0.45288215, -0.45123853, -0.44959182]
   time        ff       T vector         dist  windnorth  windeast  wind_diff
0   1.0  3.025026  343260.686560   384.268454  -7.708282 -0.452882  -7.255400
1   2.0  3.014953  342124.216844   767.952869  -7.715065 -0.451239  -7.263827
2   3.0  3.004900  340989.571007  1151.053039  -7.721856 -0.449592  -7.272264
0   -7.255400
1   -7.263827
2   -7.272264
Name: wind_diff, dtype: float64
```

Note, for creating plot in matplotlib you can work with pandas.Series directly, no need to store it in a list.

Comment: Hi @buran, thanks for this solution, I do want to store it in a list before since I do need to manipulate the values a bit before plotting.

Comment: Hi @buran, suppose I have a follow up question about this code, should I ask a new question or can I ask it here in a comment?

Comment: you can manipulate the df as well before plotting and change the original Series or store as new column if you prefer. What question do you have? is it related to my answer (i.e. make it more clear) or is it related to something else?

Comment: Okay that may be good to know indeed. Since the manipulation I was mentioning is related to this a bit: I want to substract the first value of the 5th column from the first value of the 4th column  to get the difference between these two. Can I do this withing the df as well immediately to get it ready for plotting?

Comment: `df['diff'] = df[5]-df[4]` this will creat new column `diff` in the DataFrame. If you prefer you can continue to refer columns by index, but overall it's better to have columns names (incl. for the original columns) as it makes your code clear - i.e. you know what each column is.

Answer (score 1):

The error comes in the `sep` attribute. If you remove it, it will use the default (the comma) which is the one you need:

e.g.

```py
>>> import pandas as pd
>>> import numpy as np
>>> file = open('data.log', 'r')
>>> df = pd.read_csv('data.log')  # or use sep=','
>>> df = list(df)
>>> df[0]
'1.00000000'
>>> df[5]
'-0.45288215'
```

Plus use `skiprows` to get out the headers.

Comment: Hi @ppanero, thanks for this solution! I am wondering however why I just get the first row value when I use df[5], shouldnt i get the whole last column instead?